# Delphi 10.2.2 IDE font size

Tags: delphi, scaling, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I would like to change the Font Size used in Delphi 10.2.2 Tokyo because it's too big.  I use 125% scaling in Windows 10.

I found this:

[System Registry Keys for IDE Visual Settings | Customizable Values](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/System_Registry_Keys_for_IDE_Visual_Settings#Customizable_Values)

But it doesn't work.

I also have Delphi XE8, and this solution from Embarcadero's website works, but not in 10.2.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you logged out of Windows and back in?

Comment: Probably related to the new IDE themes.

Comment: Yes I have logged out but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you did? *I read this help topic* doesn't tell us exactly what you *actually did*, it just shows us what the instructions told you to do.

Comment: I have installed two versions of Delphi: XE8 and 10.2.2 Tokyo. I wanted to change the font size in IDE so I modified register (added keys ModernThemes nad values  FontSize for both bds versions: 16.0 nad 19.0). XE8 looks OK now but 10.2.2 has still too big font size. I didnt do that first time. It always helped but it's first time when I have 10.2 Tokyo with update 2  and unfortunately Embarcadero's solution  doesnt work for this version.

Comment: @UweRaabe I think you are right..

Answer (score 0):

When we added theme support to the IDE in 10.2.2, for the [Dark Theme](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/new-in-10-2-2-dark-ide-theme), these settings became unused.  That's because themes carry font information.

It's a useful feature and we're looking at re-enabling it again in a future release.

Comment: Hmm thank you for your answer and I understand but is there any option to change font size for the "Light theme" ? It doesn't look good when I am using 125 % scalling in Windows 10 :/

Comment: No, not right now sorry.  When we added the dark theme support it broke this for the light theme as well.