# Can we increase the font size of the delphi IDE, like tab, menu, etc. (not only the editor)

Tags: delphi

in the last version of delphi, can we increase the font size of the delphi IDE itself, like tab, menu, etc. (not only the editor) ?

Comment: It seems not. Not in the second last version, at least: [q: Delphi 10.2.2 IDE font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48411669/delphi-10-2-2-ide-font-size).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the Delphi version. At least in Delphi 10.3.3 you can tweak the font size as described in the documentation: [System Registry Keys for IDE Visual Settings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/System_Registry_Keys_for_IDE_Visual_Settings#Customizable_Values)

Comment: Sorry! This site is experiencing technical difficulties.

Comment: Not here and now.

Comment: In Delphi 11 Alexandria you can customize the IDE font size here: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0\Theme